# How give an opportunity localize my library

Tags: android, android-resources

**Given:** library, which open own frames (fragments and activities), with own text fields and strings. Library has three files `strings.xml` for localization regions, where speak in English, Russian and Ukrainian.

**Needs:** give for user opportunity localize my library. I can't keep more languages, so it must do library's user.

**Variant of solution:** create Java-class with all text values (I has bit strings). User can set in this class values from his strings files and it take opportunity to localize by `strings.xml` file. But this varian so uncomfortable for user.

---

**Question:** how give for user opportunity to localize my library's strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solved this problem. I try to create in project (where uses library) folder with name `values-de` and put in folder `strings.xml` with strings names from library, but with another values. And it worked!

---

So: project-library can use values from project, if then defined with same names, which they defined in library-resources.